# Can we pass java complex objects(object inside object) to stored procedure? how?

Tags: java, plsql

My java object ClientData has primitive types + other java objects like Address,PhoneDetails,EmailDetails.

Tables in database are: CLIENTDETAILS, PARTNERDETAILS, ENTITYDETAILS, ADDRESS,PHONE and EMAIL

The colums of tables CLIENTDETAILS, PARTNERDETAILS, ENTITYDETAILS are mapped to primitive types of ClientData, and columns of tables ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL are mapped to 
primitive types of Address,PhoneDetails,EmailDetails objects respectively in ibator configuration

now the requirement is: I have a list of ClientData(List) in java code and want to insert values into these tables in oracle database using stored procedure.

What will be the approach to do this?
can i pass entire List to stored procedure and iterate the objects? is it possible, as i dont have much idea about stored procedures.
if not, how this can work with minimum database calls?

Thanks & Regards,
Akhilesh

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use an `ORM` tool. Please look at [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) or something similar to do this for you. Stored procedures